# Mocked UserManager and roleManager methods are returning null

Tags: asp.net, unit-testing, asp.net-core, moq, nunit-3.0

I have mocked the userManager and setup the required functions with return values.

However I keep getting a false/failed return value whenever I try to run the unit tests even though the return value I have setUp is different.

```
    [TestCase]
    public async Task Verify_UserInRole_False()
    {
        var userRole = "Supervisor";
        var email = "test@test.com";

        var mockUserStore = new Mock<IUserStore<IdentityUser>>();
        var mockUserRoleStore = mockUserStore.As<IUserRoleStore<IdentityUser>>();
        var mockedUserManager = new Mock<UserManager<IdentityUser>>(new Mock<IUserStore<IdentityUser>>(mockUserRoleStore).Object,
                new Mock<IOptions<IdentityOptions>>().Object,
                new Mock<IPasswordHasher<IdentityUser>>().Object,
                new IUserValidator<IdentityUser>[0],
                new IPasswordValidator<IdentityUser>[0],
                new Mock<ILookupNormalizer>().Object,
                new Mock<IdentityErrorDescriber>().Object,
                new Mock<IServiceProvider>().Object,
                new Mock<ILogger<UserManager<IdentityUser>>>().Object);


        mockedUserManager.Setup(x => x.FindByEmailAsync(email))
        .ReturnsAsync(It.Is<IdentityUser>(u => u.UserName == email));

        mockUserRoleStore.Setup(x => x.IsInRoleAsync(It.Is<IdentityUser>(u => u.UserName == email), userRole, It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
        .ReturnsAsync(true);

        AdminController adminController = new AdminController(hostingEnvironment, signInManager, logger, roleManager, mockedUserManager.Object);
        var actionResult = await adminController.CheckIfUserIsInRole(email, userRole);
        Assert.IsTrue(actionResult);
    }
```

Method to be Tested:

```
public async Task<bool> CheckIfUserIsInRole(string email, string role)
{
    return await _userManager.IsInRoleAsync(await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(email), role);
}
```

The same persists for various methods of the userManager like *AddToRole()*; etc

**As per my understanding:**
As I am mocking the *IsInRoleAsync()*,
as soon as the *CheckIfUserIsInRole(...)* method is hit, 
The *IsInRoleAsync()* should be replaced by the mock object and should return whatever we have configured the mock object to return.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the setup of your mock. If you use particular object or value `moq` will compare the instances by using `IEquatable.Equals`. You have the following setups:

```
mockedUserManager.Setup(x => x.FindByEmailAsync(email))
    .ReturnsAsync(new IdentityUser { UserName = email });

mockUserRoleStore.Setup(x => x.IsInRoleAsync(new IdentityUser() { UserName = email }, userRole, ct))
    .ReturnsAsync(true);
```

Since you every time create the new instance your setups are never actually matched. Consider changing the second setup to something like:

```
mockUserRoleStore.Setup(x => x.IsInRoleAsync(It.IsAny<IdentityUser>(), userRole, It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
    .ReturnsAsync(true);
```

or more specifically

```
mockUserRoleStore.Setup(x => x.IsInRoleAsync(It.Is<IdentityUser>(u => u.UserName == email), userRole, It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
    .ReturnsAsync(true);
```

**Update**

I have noticed one more problem as you are not initializing your `mockedUserManager` with the mocked `mockUserRoleStore` but with the new mock instance:

```
var mockUserRoleStore = mockUserStore.As<IUserRoleStore<IdentityUser>>();
var mockedUserManager = new Mock<UserManager<IdentityUser>>(mockUserRoleStore.Object,
    new Mock<IOptions<IdentityOptions>>().Object,
    new Mock<IPasswordHasher<IdentityUser>>().Object,
    new IUserValidator<IdentityUser>[0],
    new IPasswordValidator<IdentityUser>[0],
    new Mock<ILookupNormalizer>().Object,
    new Mock<IdentityErrorDescriber>().Object,
    new Mock<IServiceProvider>().Object,
    new Mock<ILogger<UserManager<IdentityUser>>>().Object);
```

Comment: Hi I tried the approach; but still getting the same result; I refactored the code to help in debugging. The userManager.FindByEmailAsync() in the actual actual function returns null which is probably the problem; but regardless of the argument I am passing to the RoleStore method; shouldn't it give me the mocked return I directed it to give?

Comment: @AbhilashGopalakrishna `moq` tries to match the invocation with the setup but in your case setup has new instance which is always different from the instance in the actual invocation. I updated the answer, found one more issue.

Comment: That was a stupid mistake; thank you:) I have updated the new code after trying your suggestions. I am still getting the same return value of false. This is probably another invocation mistake I have made.Any obvious mistakes you can see in the edit?. Thank you very much:)

Comment: @AbhilashGopalakrishna `.ReturnsAsync(It.Is<IdentityUser>(u => u.UserName == email));` this is wrong  because it will return null actually :), revert it back to the previous implementation...

Comment: Hi thank you:) that solved the null user problem; I was doing a grave mistake.:)
I was using userManager.IsInRoleAsync but was mocking the IsInRoleAsync in the rolestore. I have not seen how the usermanager calls the IsInRoleAsync. but that seems to solve the problem ; thank you:)